SQL Query in Groovy returning null value when value is not null in database if another query runs. Not sure how queries could affect each other
I'm using groovy to import data into a LIMS. When I run my import code, I get this error:
Groovy block failed: Expression Error: "Cannot get property 'trackitemid' on null object".
Digging around, I've narrowed the issue down to this block of code:
// Check if package exists

def packagesql = """
    SELECT s_packageid
    FROM s_package
    WHERE carrier = '${fields.Carrier}'
    AND trackingnumber = '${fields.Tracking_Number}
"""

sapphire.util.DataSet packageds = getSQLDataSet(packagesql)
logger.info("exists packageds= " + packageds)

if (!fields.Tracking_Number.value) {
    logger.info("Tracking number is empty or null; no package created")
} else {
    //loop to file boxes

    for (int b = 0; b < lvboxidlist.size(); b++) {

        // Get current box trackitem
        def currentboxtrackitemsql = """
            SELECT trackitemid
            FROM trackitem
            WHERE linksdcid = 'LV_Box'
            AND linkkeyid1 = '${lvboxidlist.get(b)}'
        """

        sapphire.util.DataSet currentboxtrackitemds = getSQLDataSet(currentboxtrackitemsql)
        logger.info("currentboxtrackitemsql= " + currentboxtrackitemsql);
        logger.info("currentboxtrackitemds= " + currentboxtrackitemds);

        currentboxtrackitem = currentboxtrackitemds.trackitemid[0];
        logger.info("currentboxtrackitem =" + currentboxtrackitem);
}

There is a logger line for the query and if I go grab it and run it in SSMS, it brings back the value I'm looking for, so it's not that the data doesn't exist, or the query is wrong.
What stumps me is that if I comment out the package check like so:
//// Check if package exists
//def packagesql = """
//    SELECT s_packageid
//    FROM s_package
//    WHERE carrier = '${fields.Carrier}'
//    AND trackingnumber = '${fields.Tracking_Number}
//"""
//sapphire.util.DataSet packageds = getSQLDataSet(packagesql)
//logger.info("exists packageds= " + packageds)


if (!fields.Tracking_Number.value) {
    logger.info("Tracking number is empty or null; no package created")
} else {

 
    //loop to file boxes
    for (int b = 0; b < lvboxidlist.size(); b++) {
        // Get current box trackitem
        def currentboxtrackitemsql = """
            SELECT trackitemid
            FROM trackitem
            WHERE linksdcid = 'LV_Box'
            AND linkkeyid1 = '${lvboxidlist.get(b)}'
        """

        sapphire.util.DataSet currentboxtrackitemds = getSQLDataSet(currentboxtrackitemsql)
        logger.info("currentboxtrackitemsql= " + currentboxtrackitemsql);
        logger.info("currentboxtrackitemds= " + currentboxtrackitemds);

        currentboxtrackitem = currentboxtrackitemds.trackitemid[0];
        logger.info("currentboxtrackitem =" + currentboxtrackitem);
}

It works! I'm self taught at groovy (if that's not obvious already) and so am afraid I'm missing something totally boneheaded, but I can't figure out why the package query would affect the trackitem query when they don't share any variables.
I can't get rid of the package check because I may have multiple manifests to import from the same package and I want to make sure I don't create multiple database entries for a single package.
I tried running the output query from the log directly against the database. No issue there; it brings back expected value(s).
I've tried moving the package query around (Moved it before the loop, moved after the box trackitem query) but it doesn't change anything. I'm honestly not sure what else to try, since I don't understand why commenting out the package query would allow the box trackitem query to run.

AND trackingnumber = '${fields.Tracking_Number} just like that, with no closing quote?

Oh god that's it. That's kind of embarrassing for my first post, but I figured it had to be something boneheaded that I had stared at it too long to see. Thank you so much! Using this to add fuel to my "I need a proper IDE on this work laptop" request.

So I think @Iterokun found the underlying issue as to why things fail, but I think you are doing some unnecessary things that lead you down this path of failure.
def packagesql = """
    SELECT s_packageid
    FROM s_package
    WHERE carrier = '${fields.Carrier}'
    AND trackingnumber = '${fields.Tracking_Number}   <<-- this is your error
"""

The above statement with the unmatched closing ' is causing you issues.  However, the fix is not to add the closing quote.  Groovy's use of GStrings for parameter substitution is way better than mere String substitution.  To demonstrate what I mean consider these two statements:
def packagesql = """
    SELECT s_packageid
    FROM s_package
    WHERE carrier = '""" + ${fields.Carrier} + """'
    AND trackingnumber = '""" + ${fields.Tracking_Number} + """'
"""

This may be how you understand GStrings in general, but it doesn't hold up when using then in SQL statements.
def packagesql = """
    SELECT s_packageid
    FROM s_package
    WHERE carrier = ${fields.Carrier}
    AND trackingnumber = ${fields.Tracking_Number}
"""

While these two statements will produce the same DB results.  These two statements ARE NOT FUNCTIONALLY equivalent.  It may seem strange that I used the plus operator, but I had to make my point.
The first statement is using the + operator to create a string that seems like it is equivalent to using GString ${} substitution syntax.  But when it comes to SQL statements and the Sql class it is NOT.  In the first statement I MUST surround the strings with single quotes because I'm literally constructing the exact string I want to send to the SQL server.  BUT, this is very bad thing to do because you open yourself up to security issues in the form of SQL Injection attacks.
And this is the genius of using GString syntax over using something like the + operator.  In the second example you'll see I've removed all ' quotes around uses of ${} syntax.  That's because the Sql knows that GString substitutions are parameters being passed to the SQL DB, and must be escaped to prevent SQL Injection attacks.  So it constructs a special object called a PreparedStatement that compiles the SQL statement with placeholders for where the parameters go.  This compiled SQL statement protects you against SQL injection and then uses the underlying JDBC API to fill in those parameters in a safe way preventing the security issues that the first statement had.  Here is what is happening under the hood:
sql.query("SELECT s_packageid FROM s_package WHERE carrier = ${fields.Carrier} AND trackingnumber = ${fields.Tracking_Number}")

Is turned into the following and compiled:
"SELECT s_packageid FROM s_package WHERE carrier=? AND trackingnumber=?"

Then your variables used are passed into this at the JDBC level:
PreparedStatement ps = new PreparedStatemnt("SELECT s_packageid FROM s_package WHERE carrier=? AND trackingnumber=?")
return preparedStatement.query( fields.Carrier, fields.Tracking_Number );

And this is why you don't need the single quotes around things.  The Groovy/Java data types tell the JDBC driver what to do.  Because these parameters are Strings it knows how to do it without using literals.
Using GStrings with ${} substitutions protects your code from security vulnerabilities where using raw Strings will not.  Raw Strings are ok to use when you don't need to run parameterized SQL statements using variables from your code, but that is rare.
This is why constructing SQL statements by combining raw strings (ie literal + variable + literal etc) is dangerous, and why constructing dynamic SQL is dangerous too.
One thing to note.  In your code you had a second SQL statement that contained a String literal:
        def currentboxtrackitemsql = """
            SELECT trackitemid
            FROM trackitem
            WHERE linksdcid = 'LV_Box'
            AND linkkeyid1 = ${lvboxidlist.get(b)}
        """

In that case you DO want to use ' to surround LV_BOX so SQL understands that is a String literal.  Since it's not coming from variables in your code you DO need to surround it with single quotes.  Hope this helps your understanding of GString in SQL queries.
